# Onsen-UI cannot load <ons> tags in Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, onsen-ui

I am trying to move avatars pattern of Onsen UI (http://onsen.io/pattern-list_avatars.html) into a Meteor app, but the  tags do not load. Firebug logged message from Onsen:

> Onsen UI require jqLite. Load jQuery after loading AngularJS to fix this error. jQuery may break Onsen UI behavior.

This message appeared even though I had jquery package installed and in order to eliminate it I have to include jquery lib into client/lib folder (do not know if that is correct).

I have also added urigo:angular package into my project because Onsen requires Angular but that did not do the trick. Now the only message I get in the log is

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

Which is taken from Onsen code:

```
if (window.angular.bootstrap) {
//AngularJS is already loaded, so we can return here...
console.log('WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.');
return;
}
```

The styling is not applied to elements and they look the following:[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: What files are you using for Onsen UI? If you use onseui_all.js AngularJS is already included so you don't need to load it. If you use the normal onsenui.js you need to load angular.js also. Please load in this order if you're using jQuery: angular -> onsen -> jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onsen .js files need to be loaded in a correct order together with jQuery file and Angular file. To achieve this in Meteor I loaded these files in client/lib folder like this:

```
root
  |- client
    |- lib
     - onsen.js
      |- jQuery
       - jquery.min.js
        |- Angular
         - angular.min.js
```

Loading in this way solved the problem because meteor load files starting from the deepest node in the folder tree, in this case /Angular folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution will be to create an onsen Meteor package and make a dependency to Jquery and Angular Meteor packages.