# Meteor & Angular & Onsen UI: Jquery loading order

Tags: angularjs, meteor, onsen-ui

Today I started from scratch on a new project and I want to use Onsen-ui with Meteor. Since Onsen-ui requires Angular, I ran into some issues, which have been discussed before on Stackoverflow:

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29227819/1778412

AngularJS is loaded into my app by using the urigo:angular package from atmosphere and Onsen-ui is included by putting both the JS and CSS file in the client/lib folder.

Here comes the tricky part.

> Onsen UI require jqLite. Load jQuery after loading AngularJS to fix
>   this error. jQuery may break Onsen UI behavior.

This message was printed in the browser's console. I wonder if it even possible to include Onsen-ui in a Meteor project. On atmosphere no package has been published that solves the dependency problems. It would be great if someone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: How do you include Onsen-ui?

Comment: Here's the repository of my test case:https://github.com/fullhdpixel/Onsen-Angular/tree/master/client/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to solve this would be to create a Meteor package for Onsen-UI and in the package.js file define the right dependencies and loading order, but if you don't want to do that, here is another answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29227819/1426570

Comment: yes, Ive seen your answer (see link in OP) and prefer to go the easy route. Could you point out the solution in the repo I linked you?

Comment: There seems to be no way to load Jquery after angular (either with your package or without) in Meteor.

Comment: That's because we have a weak dependency on Jquery. it means that if it's already there, it will load before angular but if it's not there it won't load.  why JQuery lite is not enough for your needs?

Comment: I dont need JQuery, but Meteor comes with this by default!?! It would be very helpful if you could create a very simple base view with onsen ui & angular. There's not much more than I need from there. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Even though I look at this as a Onsen-ui bug, you can do this with https://atmospherejs.com/planettraining/angular-meteor-platform

Comment: I removed the default meteor-platform. There is an error coming from the angular.min.js file. The initial problem with Jquery seems to be solved though.